# Return a string from a vector containing a string and a number

Tags: list-manipulation

I currently have a List of the form,

```
{{String_1, 8.}, {String_2, `101.}, {String_3, 37.}, ..., {String_n, 28.}}
```

Along with another list,

```
{{8, 37, ... }, ..., {..., 28, 101}}
```

And I would like to return,

```
{{String_1, String_3, ...}, ..., {..., String_n, String_2}}
```

In short, I would like to replace the lists of numbers in the second list with their corresponding strings (given in the first list). I imagine this has quite a simple solution, but searching through Mathematica's documentation hasn't been very fruitful. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `{{8, 37, ... }, ..., {..., 28, 101}} /. (#2 -> #1 & @@@ {{String_1, 8.}, {String_2, 101.}, {String_3, 37.}, ..., {String_n, 28.}})` or `{{8, 37, ... }, ..., {..., 28, 101}} /. (Rule @@@ Reverse /@ {{String_1, 8.}, {String_2, 101.}, {String_3, 37.}, ..., {String_n, 28.}})`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some data

```
data = Table[{"string_" <> ToString[i], i}, {i, 1, 10}];
```

Convert the data involving `String` into rules using `Rule`.

```
rule=(data/.List[a_,b_]-> Rule[b,a])
```

Arbitrary input data `tab` given as a list and you obtain the result applying the above rule assignment `rule`

```
tab=Table[RandomChoice[Range[10]], {i, 1, 5}, {j, 1, 8}, {k, 1,10}];
tab/. rule
```

> {{{string10,string6,string3,string7,<<3>>,string1,string5,string3},<<7>>},<<4>>}

BR

Answer (score 2):

If your data is stored as:

```
list = {{"String1", 8}, {"String2", 101}, {"String3", 37}, {"String4",28}}
anotherlist = {{8, 37, 8}, {28}, {28, 101}};
```

...this will give you your result:

```
ReplaceAll[anotherlist, MapThread[Rule, Transpose[Map[Reverse, list]]]]
```

> output: {{"String1", "String3", "String1"}, {"String4"}, {"String4","String2"}}

Explanation:
ReplaceAll replaces his first argument with the rules in the second argument.
I think there are several ways to make a list of rules, but i personally find the combination of the functions MapThread and Rule very convenient and easy to use.

Comment: Hmm... I should have checked PlatoManiac's answer before submitting mine...Basically the same method, slightly different notation.